# I keep getting an "unexpected character" and an "unrecognized data type" errors when creating a stored procedure in sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I am trying to create a stored procedure based off of a code I found online,this is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customers_CRUD]
      @Action VARCHAR(10)

AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;


      --INSERT
      IF @Action = 'INSERT'
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Table
            VALUES (a, b)
      END

      --UPDATE
      IF @Action = 'UPDATE'
      BEGIN
            UPDATE table
            SET Name = @Name, Country = @Country
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END

      --DELETE
      IF @Action = 'DELETE'
      BEGIN
            DELETE FROM Table 
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END
END
```

Using this database:

```
**friend**-->
 Content:user_id,friend_id;
  **user**-->
    Content:user_id,email,password;
      **user_extra**-->
         Content:user_id,name,surname,birth_date,country_of_birth,user_name;
```

Now I keep getting an error on line 1:

> "Unexpected character.(near[)", 
>   "Unexpected character.(near [)"

and an error on line 2:

> "Unrecognized data type.(near))"

now I checked my code and can not find mistakes but I do not know why I keep getting these error can someone care to explain,new to mysql and btw I was using this in the phpmyadmin sql section.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use square brackets.  That's SQL Server syntax.

Comment: The use of `NOCOUNT` and rampant omission of `;`'s also points to this being designed for SQL Server.

Comment: So how do I replace them?For it to work with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  SP_Name(IN Action VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON ;


      --INSERT
      IF (@Action = ‘INSERT’) THEN
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Table
            VALUES (a, b)
      END
      END IF ;
      --UPDATE
      IF( @Action = ‘UPDATE’) THEN 
      BEGIN
            UPDATE table
            SET Name = @Name, Country = @Country
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END
    END IF ; 
      --DELETE
      IF (@Action = ‘DELETE’) THEN 
      BEGIN
            DELETE FROM Table 
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END
  END IF ;
END
```

i think this should work for you 
  read about how to create procedure syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) also about how to use the IF statement Syntax in mysql[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) and you might want to check how to declare variables too , because this code should be fine but the NONCOUNT variable is not defined , read about declaring variables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html)